# using list instead of number or string in the query

Tags: python, web2py

I would like to use a list of int to be used in a query as below:

```
db.define_table('customer',Field('name'),Field('cusnumber','integer'))

def custmr():
    listOfNumbers=[22,12,76,98]
    qry=db(db.customer.cusnumber==listOfNumbers).select(db.customer.name)
    print qry
```

this arise an issue that the only accepted data type in the query is int or str.

Is there any way to avoid this issue (preferably by not using for loop)

Regards

Comment: A list of numbers is not an integer.  Why don't you try joining them into, say, a comma-separated string or something

Comment: Do you want to filter it for all numbers within listOfNumbers individually or the  cusnumber is a field that contains list of numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to know what you're trying to ask, but from the syntax of `db.define_table(...)`, I take a wild guess you're on **web2py** and trying to do a query which fetch any *int* in your `listOfNumbers`.

You may use `contains` attribute like this:

```
# if all=True, cusnumber will need to contains all listOfNumbers, False means any
qry=db(db.customer.cusnumber.contains(listOfNumbers, all=False)).select(db.customer.name)
```

You can read more in details in [HERE](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/35/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#select)

As OP replied that `contains` only works for **string**, I'm going to suggest using `for/loop` will be a better answer:

```
listOfNumbers=[22,12,76,98]
for each in listOfNumbers:
     qry=db(db.customer.cusnumber==each).select(db.customer.name)
     # ... do your stuff or whatever ...
```

Comment: thanks for your help..
yes,I am using Web2py...

your solution works for string fields not int as in my previous e.g.

here your solution works:
    def custmr():
      listOfNumbers=['Adam','Jone']
        qry=db(db.customer.name.contains(listOfNumbers,all=False)).select(db.customer.cusnumber)
    print qry


my question is how to make it works for int fields as in the main question

Comment: @Abdulkareem, alright didn't realize that. then an iteration probably is the best approach, answer will be updated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the set of records for which the `cusnumber` is in `listOfNumbers`, you should use the `.belongs` method:

```
qry = db(db.customer.cusnumber.belongs(listOfNumbers)).select(db.customer.name)
```